# Noscript not working as it should in wordpress site

Tags: php, functions, javascript, html, mu-plugins

This is what I've done in my custom functions `mu-plugin`:

```
function jsdisabled() {
print '<noscript>

<div style="margin:auto; display:table; text-align:center">
<div style="margin:auto; display:table; width:70%">
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Some text.
</h2>
<p>
<img src="/noscriptimage.jpg"/>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</noscript>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'jsdisabled', 0);
```

This code adds `noscript tags` to wordpress header, but when I test the page with browser javascript disabled, what happens is that the noscript message and image will show, but the entire page content will show too, in other words, noscript is supposed to hide all the website's content and show only a message to visitors telling them to enable javascript.

You can verify it here: https://lucrebem.com.br/emp-digital/blog-de-nicho

Comment: “noscript is supposed to hide all the website's content” Why is it supposed to? That’s not how the noscript tag works, in WordPress or anywhere else.

Comment: "That’s not how the noscript tag works" It is, unless something changed in the last year.

Comment: noscript has never worked that way. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript).

Comment: **That's not how `noscript` works**, if you want it to work that way you would need to put a stylesheet inside your noscript tag that hides the page. It has never worked the way you described

Answer (score 3):

That's not how `<noscript>` tags work, and if they did your usage is incorrect.

> The `<noscript>` tag defines an alternate content to be displayed to
> users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser
> that doesn't support script.
>
> The `<noscript>` element can be used in both `<head>` and `<body>`.
> When used inside `<head>`, the `<noscript>` element could only contain
> `<link>`, `<style>`, and `<meta>` elements.

The contents of a noscript tag only show if javascript is disabled, that's it. Additionally, you can't put images and paragraphs in the `<head>` tag, even inside a `<noscript>`.

If you want to hide your site and display a message if the user has disabled javascript, it's not enough to use a `<noscript>` tag, you need to apply CSS to hide the site, and you need to put your message noscript inside the `<body>` tag.

Further reading:

- https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_noscript.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript